# How to write just 1 sentence that has 2 or more relative clauses?

Tags: relative-clauses

Let see this sentence:

**Most people, who drink cold water, I knew, have never got any sore throat.**

am i writing the above sentence correctly?

The above sentence can be broken down as following:

-Most people, who drink cold water, that I knew

-These people have never got any sore throat

**So, How to write just 1 sentence that has 2 or more relative clauses?**

Comment: No, it's not grammatical. If you mean "I knew" to be a relative clause, it isn't. Not in that position. And those commas make the correct relative clause (_who drink cold water_) nonrestrictive, and nonrestrictive relative clauses can't modify nonspecific indefinites like _most people. A grammatically correct version would be _Most people I know who drink X have never got Y_ (in the US that would be "gotten", but I can see you're not doing American English).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sentence is correct aside from a small grammatical error.

Correct version: *Most people, who drink cold water, I knew, have never gotten sore throats.*

Parenthetical analysis is useful to understand why it's correct. Replacing the outer commas of the clauses with parentheses makes this: *Most people (who drink cold water, I knew) have never gotten sore throats.* If you take away the phrase in parentheses you still have a complete sentence.

Also, this sentence only has one relative clause. A relative clause begins with a relative pronoun or a relative adverb. The first clause follows this by using *who* while the second clause just starts with the subject *I*.